# apkbuilder finds duplicate file when adding powermock to an android test project

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm attempting to add powermock-mockito and mockito into an Android Test project. I created the android test project using the android command-line tool to create the build.xml and project structure. I have the following jars in my libs/ directory:

- dexmaker-1.0.jar
- dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar
- mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
- powermock-mockito-1.5-full.jar

When I attempt to build the project with ant debug, I get the following error:

```
[apkbuilder] Creating ProjectTests-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
[apkbuilder] Found duplicate file for APK: mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
[apkbuilder] Origin 1: /home/cmiller/Projects/android-project/ProjectTests/libs/powermock-mockito-1.5-full.jar
[apkbuilder] Origin 2: /home/cmiller/Projects/android-project/ProjectTests/libs/powermock-mockito-1.5-full.jar

BUILD FAILED
/home/cmiller/Applications/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:951: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/cmiller/Applications/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:962: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/cmiller/Applications/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:319: com.android.sdklib.build.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK
```

I'm not sure how it's finding a duplicate file in a single jar. The build.xml file hasn't been modified at all and I haven't created a custom_rules.xml. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the duplicate class `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` from one of the jars. I solved this by doing the following:

1. Make backup copy of `powermock-mockito-1.5-full.jar`
2. Rename `powermock-mockito-1.5-full.jar` to `powermock-mockito-1.5-full.zip`
3. Unzip `powermock-mockito-1.5-full.zip`
4. `rm -rf mockito-extensions`
5. `jar cf powermock-mockito-1.5-full.jar META-INF/ org/`
6. Put the updated jar in the libs folder.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked if the file really is duplicated in the jar file? Afaik it is possible to have the same file twice in a zip file. In that file removing that from the jar could help. No idea how it would get there though.

Comment: It didn't exist more than once. I think ultimately the problem lies with androids default testing framework not working with anything that does byte-level manipulation like mocking frameworks. I may have to try something else to be able to do any reasonable TDD in android.

Comment: I had this exact same problem and indeed, the powermock-mockito-1.5-full.jar had a duplicate file called "org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker" under "mockito-extensions" folder. I mean c'mon, I wasted hours on debugging this. The library was released last December and there's still a ridiculous issue like this present. Jeez..