# How to get Powermock to work with Dexmaker

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermock, dexmaker

I am trying to incorporate [Powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) as a dependency for my Android tests using the following build.gradle configuration:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    androidTestCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5')
    androidTestCompile('com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2')
    androidTestCompile('com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2')
    androidTestCompile('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.5.5') {
        exclude module: 'junit'
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.5.5') {
        exclude module: 'mockito-all'
    }
}
```

However, the compiler is complaining that

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebugTest'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
    File 1: ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito/1.2/b99884a4c6ef6335ba376f79aa79632b2421c17c/dexmaker-mockito-1.2.jar
    File 2: ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito/1.2/b99884a4c6ef6335ba376f79aa79632b2421c17c/dexmaker-mockito-1.2.jar
```

Looking into the jar structure, I noticed that both Dexmaker and Powermock declare a `MockMaker` in `mockito-extensions`

[image: img]

What is a MockMaker? How do they differ? 
And the most important question: Is it possible to get Powermock to work nicely with Dexmaker?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MockMaker is a glue module that integrates dexmaker with Mockito. It does what's necessary for Mockito to generate concrete classes with Dalvik .dex files instead of JVM .class files.

It's possible that Powermock will work with Dexmaker, but it's unlikely advanced Powermock features will work. In particular, Powermock [advertises this](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/):

> *PowerMock uses a custom classloader and bytecode manipulation to enable mocking of static methods, constructors, final classes and methods, private methods, removal of static initializers and more.*

That custom class loader is unlikely to work on dalvikvm.

Answer (score 3):

you can try to put this in your build.gradle, it solved to me the same problem

```
android{
...

packagingOptions{
    exclude 'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'
}

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i just found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796858/apkbuilder-finds-duplicate-file-when-adding-powermock-to-an-android-test-project). It involves a bit of manual work and you will have to modify the jar file yourself.

So what [nparihar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719759/nparihar) suggests is the following.

1. Make backup copy of powermock-api-mockito-1.5.5.jar
2. Rename powermock-api-mockito-1.5.5.jar to powermock-api-mockito-1.5.5.zip
3. Unzip powermock-api-mockito-1.5.5.zip
4. cd powermock-api-mockito-1.5.5/
5. rm -rf mockito-extensions
6. jar cf powermock-api-mockito-1.5.5.jar META-INF/ org/
7. put the new jar in your libs foler.

This solution worked for me. Let me know if it works for you as well.

Also, i can see that we are using the same dependencies. In my case i had to remove manually the hamcrest.jar and the objenesis.jar as there were confilcts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: are you suggesting dalvik then will allow the usage of this functionality and it's possible to override final methods, for example?